# DNN 5.0 skin creation help

Tags: dotnetnuke, skin

Can anyone shine some light on DNN 5.0 skin creation?Like a simple tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good posting entitled "DNN 5 Skins and skinning" in the DotNetNuke skins and themes forum at http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/109/threadid/276990/scope/posts/Default.aspx.

I also recently posted a [blog entry showing how to use the YUI Compressor and NAnt to minify any JavaScript and CSS and package your skin](http://www.aaronkjackson.com/2010/02/yui-compressor-and-nant/).